# Can I separate data for each curve?

Tags: python

I want to get the points in quadratic curve to get the quadratic equation:
 ay^2 + by + c = d

I get a set of data,

```
x = [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
  95   0  92   0  92  96   0  92  96   0  92  96   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92
   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92   0  92 153   0  92   0  92   0  92 149
   0  92   0  92 146   0  92 145   0  92 144   0  92   0  92   0  92 140
   0  92 139   0  92 138   0  92 137   0  92 136   0  92 135   0  92 134
   0  92 133   0  92 132   0  92 131   0  92 130   0  92 128 129   0  92
 128   0  92 127   0  92 126 127   0  92 125 126   0  92 124 125   0  92
 124   0  92 123   0  92 122   0 121   0 120 121   0 119 120   0 118 119
   0 117 118   0 117   0 116 117   0 115 116   0 114 115   0 114   0 113
 114   0 112 113   0 112   0 111   0 110 111   0 109 110   0 109   0 108
   0 107 108   0 107   0 106   0 105 106   0 105   0 104 105   0 103 104
   0 103   0 102 103   0 102   0 101   0 100   0  99 100   0  99   0  98
  99   0  98   0  97   0  96  97   0  96   0  95  96   0  95   0  94   0
  94   0  93   0  93   0  92   0  91  92   0  91   0  90  91   0  90   0
  89  90   0  89   0  88  89   0  88  89   0  88   0  88   0  88   0  87
   0  87   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]


y = 
[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  89  90  91
  92  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128
 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146
 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164
 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182
 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200
 201 201 202 202 203 203 204 204 205 205 206 206 207 207 208 208 209 209
 210 210 211 211 212 212 213 213 214 214 215 215 216 216 217 217 218 218
 219 219 220 220 221 221 222 222 223 223 224 224 225 225 226 226 227 227
 228 228 229 229 230 230 231 231 232 232 233 233 234 234 235 235 236 236
 237 237 238 238 239 239 240 240 241 241 242 242 243 243 244 244 245 245
 246 246 247 247 248 248 249 249 250 250 251 251 252 252 253 253 254 254
 254 255 255 256 256 256 257 257 257 258 258 258 259 259 260 260 261 261
 262 262 263 263 264 264 265 265 266 266 267 267 268 268 269 269 270 270
 271 271 272 272 273 273 274 274 275 275 276 276 277 277 278 278 279 279
 280 280 281 281 282 282 283 283 284 284 285 285 286 286 287 287 288 288
 289 289 290 290 291 291 292 292 293 293 294 294 295 295 296 296 297 297
 298 298 299 299 300 300 301 301 302 302 303 303 304 304 305 305 306 306
 307 307 308 308 309 309 310 310 311 311 312 312 313 313 314 314 315 315
 316 316 317 317 318 318 319 319 320 320 320 321 321 322 322 323 323 323
 324 324 325 325 325 326 326 326 327 327 327 328 328 329 329 330 330 330
 331 331 331 332 332 332 333 333 333 334 334 334 335 335 335 336 336 336
 337 337 337 338 338 338 339 339 339 340 340 340 341 341 341 341 342 342
 342 343 343 343 344 344 344 344 345 345 345 345 346 346 346 346 347 347
 347 348 348 348 349 349 349 350 350 351 351 351 352 352 352 353 353 353
 354 354 354 355 355 356 356 356 357 357 357 358 358 358 359 359 360 360
 360 361 361 361 362 362 363 363 364 364 364 365 365 365 366 366 367 367
 368 368 368 369 369 370 370 371 371 371 372 372 373 373 373 374 374 374
 375 375 376 376 376 377 377 378 378 379 379 380 380 380 381 381 382 382
 382 383 383 384 384 385 385 385 386 386 387 387 387 388 388 389 389 390
 390 391 391 392 392 393 393 394 394 394 395 395 396 396 396 397 397 398
 398 398 399 399 400 400 400 401 401 401 402 402 403 403 404 404 405 405
 406 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419]
```

I can view there were 3 lines in the plot. Can I separate data for each curve?

or can I only extract value of the quadratic curve?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try DBSCAN algorithm, it is implemented in sklearn already.
It works well if your sample in each curve are very dense to each other in the same curve but very far from others in other curves